# Variable not updating passed ByRef

Tags: vba, excel

I am using **Option Explicit** in all modules, this one has me scratching my head, perhaps it is in the call method that things get lost.

Reading worksheets and combining particular data into a new workbook, single worksheet, the variable colData should increment the column and it will be updated and passed back in as many times as there are worksheets (ex. copy months 1-12 for a given year in cols 1-12, then the next year copy months 1-12 in cols 13-24, etc.)

Call to Function returns a Boolean (this is an error check directly afterwards):

```
  'Attempt to load Total Revenue for the Import Sheet
  TotRevLoaded = Application.Run("modGetDataHelpers.loadTotRev", wsImport, rng, colData)
```

Here are the parts of the Function that matter:
'Sub to load total revenue from selected file across the worksheets

```
Private Function loadTotRev(ByRef wsImport As Worksheet, ByRef rng As Range, ByRef colData As Long) As Boolean

'matchRow is called above and works


Dim k As Integer

    For k = 1 To 12
        'sets headers for the sheet
        wsData.Cells(1, colData) = strYear
        wsData.Cells(2, colData) = k
        'Copy Total Revenue in to row 3
        wsData.Cells(3, colData) = wsImport.Cells(matchRow, 2 + k).Value
        colData = colData + 1
    Next k
    loadTotRev = True 'Success in loading the total rev on sheet

End Function
```

colData updates in the function as one would expect 1-13, but when leaving the function and coming back for the next worksheet import it is always 1, so the value of colData is not changing at its reference address.

This one should be easy.  The variable is being converted to ByVal and once you leave the scope of the function the modifications are lost.

I thought this might be because of the arg wrap in (), Nope. Change to a sub and without assignment you can drop these.

I thought it might be due to the assignment =, Nope. Changed to Sub.

Because it is getting passed to a function, Nope. Changed to a Sub Public and Private.

Because the caller and the modifier are in different modules, Nope

Working on the solution, I don't want a global variable or to bring all helper functions into the same module scope (module global variable).

Comment: You say byRef but if you are expecting colData to return with a changed value you shouldn't use byVal as in `ByVal colData As Long`.

Comment: wsImport is a workbook that is opened, need that reference, it is assigned after file opening.  wsData is in the code workbook (named sheet).  Good catch but it is meant that way.  colData is what was giving me fits, always reset to 1, the value it was intitialized to upon return.

Comment: I apologize another good catch, that was a bad copy while I was frantically changing code, that would be a problem! edited.

Comment: I found something that works, and posted below.  I just couldn't keep this function private and call it the way it was being called.  I left the answer to help someone else that may fall into the same issue some afternoon and exert effort trying to get around it.

Comment: I'm not sure what legitimate reason one might have to use `Application.Run` to invoke a function that's statically named (i.e. you're not invoking a function name built from strings and/or variables). Make the function public, and if you don't want it exposed as a UDF, specify `Option Private Module` for its module.

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon: I will look at Option Private Module (haven't used it before), I have been in the habit of Private Subs/Functions and it is the "only"? way to call?  I am not sure if I prefer it because it forces me to recognize when I am calling something that could make widespread changes or if it stands out in the code that a call is being made so much more than just a function name tucked into a pile of code.

Comment: If it needs to be called outside the module it's in, it should be `Public`... making everything `Private` and then circumventing it with `Application.Run` is nothing more than a clever hack: I wouldn't *expect* `Application.Run` to even be able to do that. If your public space is getting too crowded, consider using class modules and objects to encapsulate functionality. Not to mention how your code happily keeps compiling after you rename one such private method, only to blow up at run-time because you forgot to update that string at the call sites.

Comment: http://www.tushar-mehta.com/publish_train/xl_vba_cases/1022_ByRef_Argument_with_the_Application_Run_method.shtml

Comment: @TimWilliams interesting. Not sure why author didn't use the existing `MSForms.ReturnBoolean` type though.

Comment: @Tim Williams, So it was the Application.Run method forcing to ByVal which is needed because of the private call to outside its own (module) scope.  MG, is probably right as usual that I need to rethink the overall structure of this project, seems strange to call a class to call a function, but then modules are treated as a "class" so its not that strange.  Is it that I might be thinking of modules as more of a an  auxiliary reference file: Using ref_file.cs or mini-namespace? Of this I am not sure.  Anyone here create a "master" sub called "Main" that controls flow for linear projects?

Comment: Not using `Application.Run` is the obvious answer here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great feedback from experienced VBA users, leading to good information.

1) @TimWilliams: Avoid the use of Application.Run to call Private Functions/Subs if you intend to pass parameters ByRef, it will caste these as ByVal.

http://www.tushar-mehta.com/publish_train/xl_vba_cases/1022_ByRef_Argument_with_the_Application_Run_method.shtml

2) @MathieuGuindon: Avoid the use of Application.Run altogether, making the Functions/Subs Public, or investigate the implementation of a class to encapsulate and protect, if truly required look at Option Private Module

I did in fact hit upon the make Public solution through trial and error, thereby dropping the Application.Run call, but the reasoning came later.