# Array passed to Sub Procedure but returned with wrong dimension size

Tags: excel, vba, function, multidimensional-array

I have an issue with the code below. Appreciate your helps.

I have created a sub ("GetListItems") that receives an Array as an argument. The sub populates the array with the data from a group of Non-contiguous Ranges in the first sheet of my excel file. Sub performs as expected and the array in the sub, after the date is assigned to it, has 2 dimensions with correct number of columns in the second dimension.

However, When I pass an array to this sub which is by reference, the returned array has only 1 dimension. I have been struggling with this the whole day and do not understand the reason. Appreciate your help.

```
Sub GetListItems(ByRef arrArray() As Variant)

Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim SelectedCols As String

' Initialize our variable and get the last row in the database
Set WS = Worksheets("Database")
LastRow = WS.Cells(WS.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

' select ranges for copying
SelectedCols = "A1:A" & LastRow & ", C1:C" & LastRow & _
             ", F1:F" & LastRow & ", H1:H" & LastRow & _
             ", V1:V" & LastRow & ", W1:W" & LastRow & _
             ", X1:X" & LastRow & ", Z1:Z" & LastRow

'Copy and paste data from defined range
WS.Range(SelectedCols).Copy
Set WS = Worksheets.Add(, Sheets(Sheets.Count))
With WS
    .Visible = xlSheetHidden
    .Paste WS.Range("A1")
End With

' Initialize array
arrArray = WS.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

' Delet the hidden sheet
With Application
    .CutCopyMode = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    WS.Delete
    .DisplayAlerts = True
End With

End Sub
```

==============================================================

```
Sub test()

Dim MyArray() As Variant
Dim Dimension As Integer, Temp As Integer
Application.Run "GetListItems", MyArray

    On Error GoTo Err
Do While True
    Dimension = Dimension + 1
    Temp = UBound(MyArray, Dimension)
Loop

Err:
MsgBox "MyArray variable has " & Dimension & " dimensions!", vbInformation And vbOKOnly


End Sub
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variable not updating passed ByRef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51313106/variable-not-updating-passed-byref)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that `Application.Run` always handles variables as `ByVal`.

You have to call your sub like this: `GetListItems MyArray` - then `ByRef` will work.

After adding this answer I found this SO-thread which is really worth reading: [Variable not updating passed ByRef](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51313106/16578424)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now it makes sense. But when I call the sub as you mentioned, I get compiler error:

Argument not optional

And When I pass the array to the sub using parentheses: GetListItems(MyArray)  I get Compiler Error: Type mismatch

Comment: Where do you get an error?

Comment: there was a typo error. It is working perfectly. Thanks a lot.